How to make my HTML + JS contact form send me an email using phpmailer() function?
I am a total beginner into the dev world and I just started learning javascript, html and CSS. I've made a website from scratch using some classes as guidance, however, the classes only show how to make the form appearance, not make it actually send emails to me.
But I've made the website live and I really wish to make this form functional. I know I can use phpmailer() to do that, however, all codes I've tested until now are not working as expected. I know basically nothing of PHP, so I am having a very hard time to troubleshoot this.
I've already set phpmailer() into my hosting and tested it and it's working, but once I try to incorporate this into the website's code, is not working.
This is the HTML code for the form:
 <section class="formcontato">
        <div id="contato" class="formcontato__contacto">
            <div class="formcontato--esquerda">
                 <img class="formcontato__img" src="assets\contact_image.png" alt="Telefone preto com flores no fundo">
            </div>
            <div class="formcontato__text">
                <h2 class="formcontato__title">Contato</h2>
                <h3 class="formcontato__subtext">Vamos conversar?</h3>
                <h3 class="formcontato__subtext">Preencha o formulário e entrarei em contato o mais rápido possível. </h3>
                <form class="formcontato__form" onsubmit="return false" method="POST">
                    <input class="formcontato__input" type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                    <span class="error-message" id="nome-error"></span>
                    <input class="formcontato__input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <span class="error-message" id="email-error"></span>
                    <input class="formcontato__input" type="text" id="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
                    <span class="error-message" id="assunto-error"></span>
                    <textarea class="formcontato__textarea" rows="5" cols="40" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="Sua mensagem"></textarea>
                    <span class="error-message" id="mensagem-error"></span>
                    <button class="formcontato__botao" onclick="sendMessage();">Enviar mensagem</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

The form is using a javascript validation that may be relevant, so here it's the full code for it:
//Conectando todos os campos para diminuir o tamanho do código
var fields = {};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    fields.nome = document.getElementById('nome');
    fields.email = document.getElementById('email');
    fields.assunto = document.getElementById('assunto');
    fields.mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem');

    Object.values(fields).forEach(field => {
        field.addEventListener('input', toggleButton);
    });

    toggleButton();
})

//Verificando os campos
function checkFields() {
    var nome = fields.nome.value.trim();
    var email = fields.email.value.trim();
    var assunto = fields.assunto.value.trim();
    var mensagem = fields.mensagem.value.trim();
    
    return nome !== '' && email !== '' && assunto !== '' && mensagem !== '';
}

function isNotEmpty(value) {
    if (value == null || typeof value == 'undefined' ) return false;
    return (value.length > 0);
}
function isEmail(email) {
    let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
function fieldValidation(field, validationFunction, errorMessage, ...args) {
    if (field == null) return false;
   
    let isFieldValid = validationFunction(field.value, ...args);
    if (!isFieldValid) {
        field.style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById(field.id + "-error").textContent = errorMessage;
    } else {
        field.style.color = '';
        document.getElementById(field.id + "-error").textContent = '';
    }
   
    return isFieldValid;
}

function maxLength(value, maxLength) {
    return value.trim().length <= maxLength;
}

function isValid() {
    var valid = true;
    
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.nome, isNotEmpty, "O Nome não pode estar vazio e deve ter no máximo 50 caracteres.") && fieldValidation(fields.nome, maxLength, "O Nome não pode estar vazio e deve ter no máximo 50 caracteres.", 50);
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.assunto, isNotEmpty, "O Assunto não pode estar vazio e deve ter no máximo 50 caracteres.") && fieldValidation(fields.assunto, maxLength, "O Assunto deve ter no máximo 50 caracteres.", 50);
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.email, isEmail, "Por favor, insira um endereço de e-mail válido.");
    valid &= fieldValidation(fields.mensagem, isNotEmpty, "A Mensagem não pode estar vazia e deve ter no máximo 300 caracteres.") && fieldValidation(fields.mensagem, maxLength, "A Mensagem não pode estar vazia e deve ter no máximo 300 caracteres.", 300);
   
    return valid;
}

//Enviando a mensagem
function sendMessage (){
    if (isValid()){
        alert ('Mensagem enviada!');
        window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
        alert ('Ocorreu um erro, confira os seus dados');
    }
}

//Desabilitar/habilitar o botão
function toggleButton() {
    var button = document.querySelector('.formcontato__botao');
    button.disabled = !checkFields(); 
}

And this is the basic PHP script the hosting gave to me, that usually works on their hosting services:
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'test@hostinger-tutorials.com';
    $mail->Password = 'EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD';
    $mail->setFrom('test@hostinger-tutorials.com', 'Mr. Drago');
    $mail->addAddress('exemplo@gmail.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');
    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer contact form';
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Name: {$_POST['name']}
Message: {$_POST['message']}
EOT;
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Message sent! Thanks for contacting us.';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Share it with us!';
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Do You Have Anything in Mind?</h1>
<?php if (!empty($msg)) {
    echo "<h2>$msg</h2>";
} ?>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></label><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></label><br><br>   
    <label for="message">Message: <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" cols="20"></textarea></label><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>

The issue is that I really wanted to make the button from the form to send the email to my inbox directly, without the need to create a new page only for that. Or in other words, I want to adapt the PHP code to make it work together with my current code in the already existing form without breaking anything.
I tried to use the basic PHP script the hosting gave to me to test and it worked. But when I tried to incorporate it into my code, the PHP stopped working. I think the issue may be related to my HTML, since I am using different classes and ids and my HTML code is more complex than the code given by the hosting.
I tried making slight changes to the PHP script to match the classes from my code, but as soon as I did that, the PHP stopped working. There are no errors messages (even with display_erros on), but the emails are not sent.
I think my HTML is missing information to link the PHP code too, but I don't know how to link them without breaking the code.
And I am worried that the javascript validation may be causing issues with the PHP too and I have no idea what needs to be adapted.
I've searched a lot on the internet, but couldn't fix. I know phpmailer() is not beginner friendly, so it makes sense. But I want to try with some help, maybe I can make it work haha
I've spent hours reading other posts here and searching on Google (and even chatgpt), but nothing actually solved my case.
Can you enlighten me on what to change into the codes to make this happen?
If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful!
Thank you!

"I know basically nothing of PHP, so I am having a very hard time to troubleshoot this." maybe it's time to learn. You can't use PHPMailer from the browser. What you can do is send the form back to PHP and then use PHPMailer. But the best/easiest might be using a mailto tag ()

window.location.reload() in sendMessage() makes the page reload instead of submitting the form. You need to add an action attribute to the form that makes it send to the PHP script. And the page script should end with a redirect back to the HTML page, instead of outputting another copy of the form.

I recommend starting with the example PHP + JS contact form example provided with PHPMailer. It's a lot simpler than what you have here.

Thanks for the tips, I will check them all. And I will study php for sure, it will be very useful. If I manage to make it work, I will post the answer here (or I may just give up and study more before trying again)

First of all if you want to use javascript verification and then process it in PHP then you should use ajax to be able to send data from javascript to PHP the if you are using JQuery library then you can write it's code like this
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("php file url",
  {
    name: "Donald Duck", //other information
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});

or pure js :
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'filename.php';
var params = 'key=value';
http.open('POST', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);

if you will struggle with ajax or xmlhttprequest lemme know and i will reply
